# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource in eclipse using deployment assembly

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I have two projects.

1. Java SE based let's say abcAPI.
2. Dynamic Web Project using tomcat server. let's say abc-web

I followed this tutorial [automatically build and include one eclipse project into another](http://codyburleson.com/2013/05/21/automatically-build-and-include-one-eclipse-project-into-another/) to include abcAPI into abc-web. So that I have clear separation between these two. I included all necessary dependencies and API's in abcAPI project as well and I believe when using deployment assembly their shouldn't be any problem because underlying referencing project already has reference to it's libraries and dependencies in its libs folder.

I see no error before execution. But after the project runs and BasicDataSource is called I get this exception.

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [com.trolix.abcAPI.cbf.SrvStart] in context with path [/abc-web] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at com.trolix.abcAPI.dbcon.DBConnection.<init>(DBConnection.java:38)
    at com.trolix.abcAPI.dbcon.DBConnection.getInstance(DBConnection.java:51)
    at com.trolix.abcAPI.dao.DAOStart.<clinit>(DAOStart.java:19)
    at com.trolix.abcAPI.controller.CtrlStart.<init>(CtrlStart.java:14)
    at com.trolix.abcAPI.manager.MgrStart.<init>(MgrStart.java:14)
    at com.trolix.abcAPI.cbf.SrvStart.doPost(SrvStart.java:55)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Uptil now I have tried many things as suggested by SO community i.e.

1. Delete Server
2. Clean server
3. Restart Eclipse
4. Build Code
5. Deploy Again
   etc.

But nothing has yet worked for me. Please guide!

Comment: I got the same error while deploying the similar application in Tomcat Server. Put the relevant jdbc jar in the lib folder of Tomcat. It should work fine.

Comment: No I am not using maven.

Comment: @GoyalVicky if adding again that library into abc-web is solution then whole point becomes baseless.

Comment: I want all dependencies to reside in abcAPI and provide the client with single concrete api, with no dependencies to add again at their end.

Comment: Its mentioned in official Tomcat documentation. See here https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html

Comment: @GoyalVicky Thank you so much. After reading the docs I got the hint what I needed. Although I downloaded and included commons-dbcp 2.1.1 before in my abcAPI and it wasn't working, I copied tomcat-dbcp.jar from tomcat's lib folder and included it in abcAPI lib folder and after setting classpath it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error using iIntelliJ IDEA, Maven, Tomcat Server. As figured out the problem was in `Artifacts`(The dependency was not included to WEB-INF/lib).

To fix it - open Project Structure -> Artifacts -> drag-and-drop commons-* from Available Elements to lib

[image]